# How to bold a font in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, fonts

I have an issue which I don't fully understand. I use font to merge subtitles in video which is installed in my laptop and everything works fine with this code:

```
-vf "subtitles=tt101.srt:force_style='FontName=Lucida Console,Style=Bold,FontSize=15,PrimaryColour=&H00111188,OutlineColour=&HFFFFFFFF,BorderStyle=4,BackColour=&H44FFFFFF,Outline=5,Shadow=0,MarginV=10'"
```

But later I found this font isn't really bold but regular. I checked in my system and indeed, there's no bold version installed, so this `Style=Bold` fragment is ignored (as I think it is). But how the hell, while using this very font in some other programs like Word, Excel, Photoshop, PotPlayer, etc, I am able to bold this font anyway? Why `ffmpeg` doesn't make it? Does these programs use something else than Windows show in the Font catalog?

Comment: names from ass [V4+ Styles] Format: `Bold=1`

Comment: http://www.tcax.org/docs/ass-specs.htm may help. (they couldn't come up with a funnier title than `ass-specs` if they tried)

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов I think your solution works. However, to make sure this font is bolder I had to see it in stack images. This is maybe characteristic of this particular font, and it not quantizes to 2 or 3 levels of thickness.

Comment: it looks different if: `-vf "subtitles=1.srt:force_style='Bold=1,MarginV=10',
subtitles=1.srt:force_style='Bold=0,MarginV=50'"`